# One login view, sign up or login

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, parse-platform

I want to be able to have just one login screen.  The user will enter the username, email and password every time they login.  I am having the problem where I sign up, logout and then try to login using the same credentials and I just get an error back saying that the username is already taken.  How can I just log them in if they give me the correct credentials?

```
PFUser *user  = [PFUser user];
user.email = emailEntry;
user.username = nickNameEntry;
user.password = passwordEntry;
[user signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        [MYAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"Successful login"
                                 message:@"success"
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
        [MyAlertView showAlertWithTitle:@"There was an error signing up."
                                 message:errorString
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"];
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

If user needs to sign up (first time), you need to use `–signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:`, as you are doing.

However, if he is already signed up, I guess you should use `+logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block:`.

I'm getting this infos from [this page](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFUser.html), however, I never used this SDK.

The easier way to do that is :

1. Having two buttons, that pushes different view controllers, one for signing up, the other for logging in
2. The same form, and two buttons, one which calls a methods that calls `–signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:`, and the other that calls `+logInWithUsernameInBackground:password:block:`.

With the second solution, the problem is that if you have the same form, you can't ask special informations (name, date of birth, etc.) on sign up.

**EDIT :**
You might want to have a look at :

1. [PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate.html),
2. [PFLoginViewControllerDelegate](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Protocols/PFLogInViewControllerDelegate.html),
3. [Parse API Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/index.html) (where I've found the two links above).